# dojo debugging EnhancedGrid with ItemFileReadStore

Tags: dojo

I'm following the example in "Mastering Dojo", Chapter 3, with dijox.grid.Grid. I've modified it slightly to use dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid. I've written a web service that returns some json in the format required by dojo. I've tested the web service independently and it returns the correct json. But when I put EnhancedGrid together with ItemFileReadStore it does not produce any errors in the browser error console but also does not display any data in the grid.

What steps can I take from here to debug this? Is there some verbose debugging flag I can give to dojo so that it (hopefully) clues me into what is going wrong?

EDIT:

Here's what I'm doing:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true, isDebug:true"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/resources/dojo.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/claro/EnhancedGrid.css"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/EnhancedGrid_rtl.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            dojo.require("dojo.parser");
            dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
            dojo.require("dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid");
        </script>
    </head>
    </body class="claro">
        <style>
        #msgs {
            width=550px;
            height=200px;
        }
        </style>
        <div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId="xstore" url="/path/to/my/resource/data.json"></div>
        <table id="msgs" dojoType="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" store="xstore">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th field="id" width="50">Id</th>
                    <th field="ts" width="100">Date</th>
                    <th field="msg" width="400">Message</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The javascript returned is like this:

```
{
    "identifier":"id",
    "items":[
        {
            "id":"3425",
             "custId":"2342525225",
            "ts":"2011-07-23T07:00:00Z",
             "msg":"test message"
        }
    ]
}
```

I guess one open question: the json has one extra column that's not displayed in the table ("custId"). I'm hoping that this does not cause problems?!

EDIT2:

Also if I go into firebug's DOM console, I can see that xstore variable correctly holds the data from the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two things that work are:

setting an inline style on the table to set the width/height, OR

set the EnhancedGrid property autoHeight which is what I ended up doing.